# How do I import `org.springframework.boot.test.*` with VS Code?

Tags: spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I'm learning spring boot following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/aRLoSDOlU3w?t=1276)

[image]

I've imported all the dependencies as the tutorial does

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency> -->
</dependencies>
```

However, I can't import `org.springframework.boot.test`

The only difference between mine and the tutorial is that I'm using VS Code while the tutorial uses STS as the IDE

How do I import `org.springframework.boot.test.*` with VS Code?

Comment: Are you sure that all dependencies are downloaded? I looked at the project structure and compiled it at my local, everything looks OK. I did not faced any problem. Make sure that run -> mvn clean install

Comment: @AlperDerya Thank you. I tried all kinds of clean but still got that error. Are you using the exact pom.xml I put in my OP?

Comment: Yes. I visited the website you shared, downloaded related project. It can not depend on the IDE you used. I am using IntelliJ by the way. Is there any error or warning message in console?